# Why is the Synology NAS not starting the VPN connection automatically

Tags: vpn, network-attached-storage

Our remote Synology NAS box is configured to connect to the local NAS box via VPN.

**Reconnect when the VPN connection is lost** is ticked in the **Control Panel** -> **Network**->**Network Interface** section.

[image]

However, if the NAS box restarts, VPN connection is not made.

**Is there a way to start the VPN connection automatically?**

Under Task Scheduler, there is VPN service to select for starting.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to pick up the remote NAS.  It works fine on my desk in my office.

So I looked for other causes and it looks like, ever since the ISP installed fibre, the connection stops and starts during the early hours, which is when the backup was taking place.